# Visual Studio 2012 for Dymola cannot compile

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dymola, openmodelica

I am new using dymola and I have a problem with my project; actually I have to transfert LNG (I am using the medium Methane_Coolprop) from one closed tank to another, it pass trough a valve to decrease the pressure, but when I start the simulation I have errors with my compiler. I will attach some images and also copy the text here, in case anyone knows what can I do please?

```
Compiling and linking the model (Visual C++).

dsmodel.c
dsmodel.c(330) : warning C4133: 'fonction': types incompatibles - de 'DymStruc0 *' 'ExternalThermodynamicState *'
dsmodel.c(418) : warning C4133: 'fonction': types incompatibles - de 'DymStruc0 *' 'ExternalThermodynamicState *'
dsmodel.c(766) : warning C4133: 'fonction': types incompatibles - de 'DymStruc1 *' 'ExternalSaturationProperties *'
Cration de la bibliothque dymosim.lib et de l'objet dymosim.exp
ExternalMediaLib.lib(CoolPropTools.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non rsolu "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::_Facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?_Facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) rfrenc dans la fonction "public: void __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Register(void)" (?_Register@facet@locale@std@@QAEXXZ)
ExternalMediaLib.lib(CoolPropTools.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non rsolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (__imp_?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) rfrenc dans la fonction "public: __thiscall std::locale::~locale(void)" (??1locale@std@@QAE@XZ)
ExternalMediaLib.lib(CoolPropTools.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non rsolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Incref(void)" (__imp_?_Incref@facet@locale@std@@QAEXXZ) rfrenc dans la fonction "class std::codecvt<char,char,int> const & __cdecl std::use_facet<class std::codecvt<char,char,int> >(class std::locale const &)" (??$use_facet@V?$codecvt@DDH@std@@@std@@YAABV?$codecvt@DDH@0@ABVlocale@0@@Z)
dymosim.ex_ : fatal error LNK1120: 3 externes non rsolus
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExternalMedia cannot be used with MSL 4.0.0 at the moment, you will have to use an older version of the MSL (see ReadMe of ExternalMedia here https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ExternalMedia/tree/v.3.3.0-dev) . I would suggest to make sure that the example models of the ExternalMedia are working properly before using the media models in your own components.

If the problem persists, a code example would help a lot to answer your question.